# WebSocket/Apache Error AH01991: SSL input filter read failed

Tags: apache, websocket

I'm trying to use Apache's `mod_proxy_wstunnel` to proxy data between a client website and a back end WebSocket server, but it seems like Apache is resetting the socket.

My server/client code is very simple at the moment:

Client JS:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://local-test.mysite.com/wss/", "basic-protocol");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log('open: ', e);
};
socket.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log('error: ', e);
};
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('message: ', e);
};
socket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log('close: ', e);
};
```

The server code (C++) is a little more complex, but essentially it does the following (some `struct` details left out for briefness):

```
int server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
bind(server, ...); // binds to port 4433
listen(server, 1024);
int client = accept(server, ...);

char buff[4096];
long r = recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

This bit works, as once my JS loads up and creates the `WebSocket`, my server gets the following HTTP data:

```
GET /wss/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4433
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: { user agent string }
Origin: https://local-test.mysite.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: { cookie data here }
Sec-WebSocket-Key: {base64 key}
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: basic-protocol
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.11.1
X-Forwarded-Host: local-test.mysite.com
X-Forwarded-Server: local-test.mysite.com
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
```

Which I then parse out the `Sec-WebSocket-Key`, append the "magic string" (`"258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"`), get the SHA1 hash, base64 encode that, and then send along the following response back:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n
Upgrade: websocket\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {hashed response key}\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: basic-protocol\r\n\r\n
```

My server then goes back to `recv` to wait for the next bit of data (which I'd send from a button in the DOM), but immediately errors out with a `ECONNRESET` error while the JS websocket closes with error code 1006 (abnormal termination), and my Apache log reports the following:

```
[ssl:info] (70014)End of file found: [client 192.168.11.1:54673] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

I'm not sure if I've got my Apache config set correctly to proxy data or if it's my server response code, but here's my Apache config (for the relevant virtual host):

```
Listen local-test.mysite.com:80
Listen local-test.mysite.com:443
<VirtualHost local-test.mysite.com:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost local-test.mysite.com:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite
    DocumentRoot "/Code/source/dev/web"
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/web/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/web/access.log common
    ServerName local-test.mysite.com 
    ServerAlias local-test
    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mysite.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mysite.key

    <Directory /Code/source/dev/web>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L,NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp|svg|ico)$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$
        RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </Directory>

    # Websocket config
    SSLProxyEngine on

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /wss ws://localhost:4433 keepalive=On enablereuse=On connectiontimeout=1800
    ProxyPassReverse /wss ws://localhost:4433

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:4433%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried all sorts of variations for the `ProxyPass` and `Rewrite` rules, to no avail.

My environment:

- Apache/2.4.51 (Fedora)
- Chrome Version 103.0.5060.53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was actually my server reply and *not* my Apache config:

First, my base64 encoded string was of the "stringized" SHA1 hash instead of the binary version (e.g. `b1feae...` instead of `0xb1 0xfe 0xae ...`), and secondly I wasn't explicitly returning the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` in certain instances (to which FireFox didn't seem to care about in some of my tests while Chrome did and would close the connection [as it should]).